# Dropping iPhone 4S Support

Tags: ios, iphone

The iPhone 4S is the oldest iPhone still to be supported by Apple, which as such runs iOS 8, a requirement of my own app.

However, as hard as I am trying, my app experience is being worsened due to the fact I keep having to adapt to the tiny (y comparison) screen size of the iPhone 4S.

Is it possible in any way to drop support for a device? Or as it runs iOS 8, do I have no way of doing so? Is it a case of, if I release it on iOS 8 for iPhone, it WILL be available for iPhone 4S owners?

Comment: Drop a support for any device and Apple will reject your application. By the way - I've been developing an app that works on iOS7+ (meaning iPhone4/4s/5/6/6+) and I have noticed that screen adjustment is seamless. I use the same dimensions for iPhone5 and above and everything suits right in place!

Comment: Had a feeling that was the case, thanks for confirmation. I'll just have to make some changes then to work everywhere!

Comment: I can only assume you are not using auto layout. You might as well adapt it now - it will solve your immediate problem, and you will better prepare yourself for the future.

Comment: I am using Auto Layout, in virtually every scenario, and it work brilliantly, there are just some certain elements of my app design which aren't working out. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: this document confirms what Shai said https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't *drop support* for iPhone 4S just yet, however you can *disable* some features when your app runs on certain undesired devices. Just make sure you state that in your app's description.

This follows the lead of GarageBand for iOS version 2.1 in which some features are only available for newer devices.

[image: GarageBand 2.1 asterisks]

PS: remember to also quote this fact in the *reviewer's notes* section.